# Ancient film where a knight rescues a princess from an evil magician

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, dragons

Ancient colour film from the 1950s-1960s. A knight goes on a quest to rescue a princess from the claws of an evil magician and his dragon.

The knight receives the help of other knights (could be seven or eight) who had been saved from a spell that had turned them into stone. In the search they all die, one by one.

There was also a two-headed monster who watched everything from a magic mirror.

Comment: There's a few users who're gonna take offence at a 1950s film being described as ancient :-)

Comment: @Valorum In my family, this film is exactly two generations old.  My father saw it in the theater, when he was the same age my daughter is now.

Comment: @Buzz Exactly. If it was too old for your father to know it, *maybe* that would count as "ancient".

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson maybe we should wait until it has completely passed from living memory before anything is labelled ancient - after all, there are still some people who remember World War I.

Comment: ancient means belonging to the very distant past/no longer in existence - neither applies to cinema

Comment: My first thought on seeing the title was, "Star Wars"? ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is *[The Magic Sword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Sword_(1962_film))* from 1962. Description from Wikipedia:

> George (Gary Lockwood) is the foster son of Sybil (Estelle Winwood), an elderly sorceress. She brought him up after his "royal parents died of the plague" in his infancy. He has fallen in love at first sight with Princess Helene (Anne Helm).
>
> She is kidnapped by the wizard Lodac (Basil Rathbone), who brazenly informs her father that he intends to feed her to his pet dragon in seven days, revenge for the death of his sister at the same age as Helene is now: 18. George wants to go on a quest to liberate his lady love, but Sybil believes he is too young (he is 20). She tries to distract the youth by showing him a magic sword, a steed, an invulnerable suit of armour, and six magically frozen knights he will command when he turns 21. The impatient George, however, tricks Sybil and locks her in a cellar, then leaves with the magical implements and revived company of knights.

[omitted are paragraphs of the quest and the knights dying off one by one]

> George sneaks into Lodac's castle and rescues Helene, only to be captured. The magician gives Helene (actually the hag in disguise) to Branton, but once he has the ring, he uses magic to put Branton's head on a plaque on the wall. George is tied up, but escapes with the help of shrunken prisoners. Sybil arrives and finally remembers the spell that restores George's powers, enabling him to slay the two-headed dragon and save Helene. Sybil steals the ring while Lodac is distracted. When the magician threatens the young couple with the seventh curse - himself - Sybil transforms herself into a large panther and kills him. The movie ends as Helene and George get married. When the six knights are returned alive, George's happiness is complete.

There is a two-headed dragon, but the two headed monster is actually a set of conjoined twins looking through the magic mirror, as seen in the trailer.

The trailer (and it's not hard to find the full movie online either):

Search terms used: *1950s film knight on a quest to save a princess*

Comment: that's it. thanks a lot for the info!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like The Magic Sword, from 1962 (also known under other titles).  There is a princess to be rescued from an evil Basil Rathbone.  The hero is aided by a group of knights who have to be unfrozen, and the evil wizard Lodac commands a two-headed dragon.  There is also a magic mirror used by the hero's Foster mother for scrying.

When it appeared on MST3K, it was admitted in one of the host segments that it wasn't really that bad of a film.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Now let's see if it's really not that bad. ;)